# 回帰結果を変数名にして呼び出す方法

Tags: r

R初心者で申し訳ございません。

重回帰分析の結果、例えば、、、

```
result <- step(reg0,direction="both",
               scope=list(upper=~○+○+...
```

の`result`を
`result1 result2 result3…result10`

といったように、最後に123…10というような変数を付けておいて
あとからループで呼び出したいと思っています。

ところが、例えば

```
t<-1
sprintf("result%s",t,sep="")
```

としても、`"result1"`は文字列になるだけで、回帰結果を呼び出すことは出来ません。

1～10までの変数を投げて回帰結果を呼び出したいのですが
どうしたらいいのでしょうか。

また、一度計算した回帰結果を、Rを一度落として再度立ち上げた後に
呼び出したいのですが、
回帰結果を保存する方法はないのでしょうか。

お恥ずかしい質問ばかりで恐れ入りますが、教えて頂けないでしょうか。

Comment: アカウントをマージしましたので、回答の承認や回答へのコメントができるようになっているかと思います。もしこちらの質問は解決したということでしたら、回答左側のチェックマークをクリックして頂けると助かります（解決済みの目印になります）

Answer (score 1, accepted):

連続したデータを保存・参照するには、配列を使用すると便利です。

```
result=array()
```

で、resultに配列を構築したあと、

```
result[1] = 1番目の回帰式
result[2] = 2番目の回帰式
```

で、順番に値を設定できます。

データは、

```
for (i in 1:10) {
    print(result[i])
}
```

と行った方法であとから参照することができます。

---

結果の保存には、`save`と`load`が使用できます。

```
save(result, file="保存ファイル名")
```

で保存が、

```
load("保存ファイル名")
```

で読み込みができます。

Answer (score 0):

kcrt さんの回答にある様に、予め解析結果を配列やリストに入れておく方が良いのですが、参考までに変数名(文字列)から変数(オブジェクト)の値を取り出す方法を記載しておきます。

```
result_set <- lapply(paste("result", 1:10, sep=""),
                     function(x){if(exists(x)){eval(as.name(x))}})
```

`as.name()` で文字列を変数シンボルに変換して `eval` しています。`lapply` を使っていますので戻り値はリストになります。また、変数が存在しない場合は `NULL` が返ります。例えば変数 `result2` が定義されていない場合は以下の様になります。

```
> result_set[[2]]
NULL
```